# How can I make Visual Studio's build be very verbose?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build-process

I need to get a hold of every flag, every switch used in the build process by the Visual Studio binaries. I tried to obtain a verbose output by using `vcbuild`, but I wasn't able.

What do I have to do to see everything performed by Visual Studio for me? It's not necessary to obtain the output in the build window. Anywhere would be fine.

Comment: Exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823854/how-to-show-command-line-build-options-in-visual-c-2008.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

1. Open the project properties dialog, then choose

   *Configuration Properties* → *C/C++* → *General*
2. Change the setting for `Suppress Startup Banner` to `No`
3. The `cl` command line(s) will be shown in the output window.

Comment: This only affect compiler not linker or resources.

Comment: In VS2017 this 'trick' doesn't seem to work anymore. However building in the developer prompt using msbuild with the solution or project filename as cli argument does show the cl call with its arguments.

Comment: @EmileVrijdags I can perfectly see the `cl` command output with VS2017 following those steps. So the "trick" works for me.

Comment: Work in VS 2019, after I changed MSBuild verbosity it didn't show anything difference, but after I did this it works.

Answer (score 216):

Menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Projects and Solutions* → *Build and Run* → *MSBuild project build output verbosity*: *Diagnostic*

Comment: This doesn't change anything. I'm still getting the same output in the output window.

Comment: Works fine for me in VC10.

Comment: @Geo it takes effect once you restart Visual Studio.

Comment: @absynce, In VS 2017 this does not take effect even on restart of Visual Studi0 2017. I am using VS 2017 community edition. So, this functionality doesn't seem implemented properly in VS 2017.

Comment: Works in VS 2019 too!

Comment: Doesn't work in VS2022. My output is extremely verbose and this setting has been on "Minimal" for ages.

Answer (score 71):

Visual Studio 2008:

Go to menu *Tools* → *Options* then *Project and Solutions* → *Build and Run* section. You have a combo box for verbosity.

C++ compiler option (project properties):

- Preprocessor - Generate Preprocessed
  File for seeing the translation unit
  as generated by preprocessor
- Advanced - Show includes - display
  included file names at compiler
  output

Comment: This does not show compile and linker flags, only file names that are being processed. Is it possible to see exact commands that are executed or this is impossible with VS?

Comment: @stefanB: you don't need special flags for this. The command lines for the compiler and linker invocation can be found in the options dialog or in the build-log that is written into the intermediate directory.

Answer (score 10):

If you're running MSBuild, you can set the /v:diag flag.

Comment: start the visual studio command prompt (it's in the Start Menu), then execute the visual studio project with: MSBuild {ProjectName}

Comment: e.g. MsBuild myProject.csproj

Comment: I see MSBuild calls `vcbuild`, but vcbuild doesn't show the flags/switches it's using.

Comment: This is the proper answer I believe. Merely switching off the suppression various banners still doesn't output everything. In particular the resource compile step was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio go to your project and right click on it and select properties. In Linker there is a command line option. There you have all the options and you can add your custom ones. Add `/VERBOSE` and when linking Visual Studio will show a lot more information.

Comment: It does show more information, but it doesn't show the tools being called to compile.

Comment: Visual Studio has a make tool called nmake. You can export your project to those makefiles and and build it from a dos console http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txcwa2xx(VS.80).aspx. Last time I did something similar (but I used CMake to generate the nmake makefiles) all the commands were printed out into the console display.