# Visual Studio 2010 output window missing debug info

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, mstest

I am trying to write some output from my unit tests using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(...)`

The problem is, each time I run the test, I cannot see the debug info in the output window. It was working fine and for some reason the debug option is now missing in show output from drop down.

Here is screenshot:
[image: Output window missing debug option"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

I noticed in my Test Results window, after running the test, next to the little success green circle , there is another icon, i doubled clicked it. It was my test results, and it included all of the types of debug messages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your build output is set to the appropriate verbosity by setting the following options in Tools > Options:

[image]

If that doesn't work, there are further suggestions available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211841/how-can-i-make-visual-studios-build-be-very-verbose).