# Retrieving Visual Studio CL commands from msbuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, cl.exe

Is there a way to retrieve the commands issued by msbuild without actually running msbuild?

Visual Studio manages to do it somehow (Project properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line), but I need to retrieve that information programatically (to feed it to clang, fyi).

I would be happy with either a command line solution a la "msbuild /givemeyourcommandswithoutactuallyrunningthem" or an add-in solution within Visual Studio.

If there is no direct way, I guess the best solution would be to write a tool that parses the (preprocessed) project file and translates the human-readable options to compiler options, e.g.

```
<PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32</PreprocessorDefinitions>
```

would become

```
/D "WIN32"
```

But I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Create a fake `cl.exe` and echo out the arguments.

Comment: As far as I can see, msbuild calls cl.exe at the exact location of the VS folder, i.e. I can't intercept it by putting a cl.exe somewhere else and manipulating PATH. So I'd have to mess around in the VS directories? I see issues coming up with that...

Comment: Rename `cl.exe` temporarily then

Comment: That would be a pragmatic solution, but not really suitable for generic use: 1. I'd need admin rights which can be difficult in the company environment. 2. cl.exe might be running already. 3. If for some reason my "extraction process" crashes, I'll be left behind with the wrong cl.exe

Comment: You can dig it out of the cl.command.*.tlog file.  There's another one for the linker.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20898409/how-can-i-capture-the-cl-exe-command-line-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: tlog looks great, thanks. I tested how it gets updated, and even with a partial build, all cpp files stay in there, with the last built getting moved to the end.

So for a tool to use the tlog file, I would check if the tlog is older than the vcxproj. If yes, do a regular build, and it will be fine.