# How to show commands issued by Visual Studio when I rebuild a solution?

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio Community 2019.
Inside Visual Studio, when I rebuild a solution, the **Output** tab shows output from *Build*.
Is it possible to show commands issued by Visual Studio which results in that output?

Comment: You can [increase the build verbosity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211841/how-can-i-make-visual-studios-build-be-very-verbose) and one of the first things in Output will be the build command and arguments