# How to show linker command line in Build output, in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, linker

This question is related to   [How to show command line build options in Visual C++ 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823854/how-to-show-command-line-build-options-in-visual-c-2008)

But in addition to showing the Compiler command line, I'd like to see the *linker* command line.

I have "unset" the /nologo option in the linker options.

[image]

But I still don't get the command line in the output window.  What do I need to do?  Is this possible?

Comment: If you look in the left-hand pane of your screenshot, just above "Manifest Tool", it says "Command Line". That's not exactly what you asked for: it is the linker command-line, but not in the output windows.

Comment: right - I want it in the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try viewing the build log? This is probably the closest to what you want to see. You view the output window, and where it says "Build log was saved at "path..."", ctrl-click on "path" and it will open the build log.

Comment: Yes - this is the closest thing.  It doesn't echo the complete command line, but only all the args.  Good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I often get burned by the wrong configuration being selected when I change things like suppress startup banner.
Did you try setting the selection when all configurations and platforms were selected?